# Why does LLVM require a new temp register identifier

Tags: llvm

I added some new tests to the compiler which generated the following but gives an expected %4 error.

```
; Entry Point
   define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** %argv) {
   entry:
      %argc_addr = alloca i32
      %argv_addr = alloca i8**
      %retval = alloca i32
      %0 = alloca i32
      store i32 %argc, i32* %argc_addr
      store i8** %argv, i8*** %argv_addr
      %1 = load i32* %argc_addr
      %2 = load i8*** %argv_addr
      call void @__llvmsharp_init(i32 %1, i8** %2)
      call i32 @__LS19ConsoleApplication37Program_mt_4Main()
      store i32 0, i32* %0, align 4
      %3 = load i32* %0, align 4
```

// error expected %4

```
      store i32 %3, i32* %retval
      br label %return

 return:
      %retval1 = load i32* %retval
      ret i32 %retval1
 }
```

Also is it wise to use unnamed temporaries ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%3`, `%4` etc are neither temporary nor registers - two concepts that do not exist in LLVM IR - instead, they are names of instructions. I suggest reading more about [single static assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) form to understand how it works.

In the textual representation of LLVM IR, non-void instructions that don't have any name are allocated numeric names such as `%3`, `%4`, and whether allocated implicitly or explicitly in the code, those numbers must be sequential. The instruction `call i32 @__LS19ConsoleApplication37Program_mt_4Main()` is a non-void one so it is implicitly allocated a number - `%3` - and so the next unnamed instruction, `load i32* %0, align 4`, should be given `%4`, not `%3`.

If you write LLVM IR by hand and have trouble with instruction naming you might consider using [my LLVM IR editor plugin for Eclipse](http://amishne.github.io/llvm-ir-editor/), it will mark such errors for you and will offer to replace any wrong numbers with the correct ones:

> [image: screenshot from the editor showing syntax error on bad name]

(notice how the unnamed `add i32 %1, 1` was implicitly allocated `%2`)

Comment: Thanks oak is it correct to write such a call as %3 = call i32 @__LS19ConsoleApplication37Program_mt_4Main()